# No such file or directory but file exists?

Tags: python, file, directory

I'm writing a python script where I need to open a ".txt" folder and analyse the text in there.

I have saved this ".txt" document in the same folder as my Python script.

But, when I go to open the file; `file = open("words.txt",'r')`

I get the error: `No such file or directory: 'words.txt'`.

I don't understand why this is happening?

Comment: Location of your script is not important, what counts is your current directory (which doesn't have to be the same as the one containing the script). Preferably use full path to your file in `open`.

Comment: Also, please use `Path` from `pathlib`, it'll handle all os paths things: `from pathlib import Path` and `file = open(Path("words.txt"),'r')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maby it's because your current working directory is different from the directory your files are stored. Try giving the full path to the file

`file = open("<full_path>\words.txt",'r')`

Answer (score 2):

- Check if there's a typo in the code or in the filename of the file
- Make sure the file is **really** under the current working directory. Sometimes similar filenames or info shown in your IDE cause confusions
- Make sure your are editing the correct script. Sometimes people copy and paste a script into different places and immediately forgot which one they are actually editing

Hope it helps.

Comment: "Make sure the file is really under the same directory with your code" => you may want to learn about the concept of "current working directory"...

Comment: You're welcome - and thanks for having corrected your answer (downvote retracted).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the directory of the `.py` file you are working with is not the same as the `.txt` file's path.

So, you need to mention the path like this:

```
file = open("C:/User/Desktop/Folder/words.txt", 'r')
```